# "pm install" command not effect on Android

Tags: android, c++, qt, qt5, adb

I have developed an application and I moved it as system app already.
However, when I tried to use shell command to install .apk file.
It run as non-effect and without error also.
Code as bellow:

```
bool ShellOperation::installPackage(QString packagePath){

LOG << packagePath;

if(!QFile(packagePath).exists()){
    LOG << "packagePath not existed";
    return false;

}else{

    QString cmd =  QString("pm install %1").arg(packagePath);

    QProcess process;
    process.start(cmd);
    process.waitForFinished(-1);

    LOG << "cmd: " << cmd;
    LOG << process.readAllStandardError();
    LOG << process.readAllStandardOutput();

    return true;
}
```

}

**Expect**: myApp.apk should be installed

**Actual**:

[ installPackage ][ 39 ] >> cmd:  "pm install /storage/emulated/0/Download/myApp.apk"

[ installPackage ][ 40 ] >> ""

[ installPackage ][ 41 ] >> ""

Are there anyone could help me?
Thanks!

Comment: any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

you should have these premission android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES for installing apk, try to invoke "pm install myapp.apk" manually via terminal emulator, maybe you will se some usefull error.

Comment: I added android.permission.INSTALL_PACKAGES. However It still not work.